# MessageSource is getting key instead of value in SpringMVC i18n

Tags: spring-mvc, internationalization, resourcebundle

I have started a new project with SpringMVC. I use messagesource structure. But Key is been looked in html page. key is "deneme.deneme". this string is looking in web page

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.yummynoodlebar.web.controller","com.yummynoodlebar.web.service","com.yummynoodlebar.web.domain"})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
   ...
@Bean(name = "labelSource")
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:resources/i18n/labels");
    ...
    return messageSource;
}}


@Component
public class ResourceManager {
@Resource(name = "labelSource")
private MessageSource messageSource;
public String getLabel(String code) {
    return messageSource.getMessage(code, null, Locale.ENGLISH);
}
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class SiteController {
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String getHomePage(Model model) {
    String str = resourceManager.getLabel("deneme.deneme");
    model.addAttribute("deneme",str);
    return "/anasayfa";
  }
}

labels_en.properties is file under the resources/i18/ directory.
{
 deneme.deneme = burak
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed error. I had done a wrong. This code "messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:resources/i18n/labels");" is wrong. It should be "messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:i18n/labels");"